# Java text properties files: is there any way to test validity?

Tags: java, parsing, properties

It looks like the [Properties.load()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) happily loads in binary garbage unless it finds an invalid `\uxxxx` escape character. Is there a way to be more strict? I just looked at the docs for [the text format of properties files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29), and I'm confused how to tell if a .properties file is valid.

---

edit: where I'm coming from with this: I figured if I pointed my application a 10MB binary file, that it would reject it. The 10MB file did get rejected, but only because of the `\uxxxx` characters.

I guess I could create a filter on the input stream to limit at some "sane" amount like 1MB, and filter out any key/value pairs where the key doesn't match an acceptable pattern. But I was hoping that it might have some minimal structure to reject grossly corrupted files.

Comment: What would it mean to be "valid" (aside from bad characters)? About all you could do is check that it starts with a valid `foo=` (or comments), and that the same is true for all non-continued lines.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ: `foo` alone in a line is equivalent to setting `foo` to the empty string.

Comment: @ninjalj Oh :( Even harder then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties files are supposed to be a generic format. It is the application's responsability to ensure that each individual property has a sane value.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29). It says, that load method throws IllegalArgumentException - if the input stream contains a malformed Unicode escape sequence.